# generating a document with list of files in a directory using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a bunch of folder with party xml files and partly binary image files.

I am generating a list of those files, using the following:

```
    <xsl:variable name="string" select="iri-to-uri(concat(@name, '/?select=*.(xml|gxf)'))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="input" select="collection($string)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$input">
    <file>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
    </file>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Works well, except of course for the binary files. How could I get the uri of those files? Is that possible with pure xslt 2.0 using saxon9he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the uri-collection() function, but that's XPath 3.0. You can therefore do it using Saxon-HE 9.6 using XQuery, but not using XSLT.

```
let $string := iri-to-uri(concat(@name, '/?select=*.(xml|gxf)'))
let $input := uri-collection($string)
for $i in $input
return
    <file>
      {tokenize($i, '/')[last()]}
    </file>
```

(We moved XQuery 3.0 and XPath 3.0 support into the HE product when they became W3C Recommendations. XSLT 3.0 has not yet reached that status.)

Comment: Great, an answer straight from the source :) Thank you very much!